# Run Javascript file on link click - MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am converting a website to MVC and cannot get this link to work properly in MVC. In the original site, this link runs a .js file that creates a game for users to destroy the site for fun. My question is, how do I get the `onclick` of this link to function properly in MVC? I have spent a lot of time looking in Stack and Google for a solution, with no luck.

```
<a id="destroy" href="javascript:var%20i,s,ss=['~/Content/bundles/dd.js'];for(i=0;i!=ss.length;i++){s=document.createElement('script');s.src=ss[i];document.body.appendChild(s);}void(0);" title="JavaScript Game">
```

Comment: you wrap your code to execute in a function and include the script in the page and when user clicks the button / link, call the function.

Comment: This is a javascript code, it doesn't have anything to do with asp.net MVC. However it worked in the original site, it should work in the new one as well, providing that you have copied all the js files to the new site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not work with IE
You should use JQuery to add Click Event, remove the Code from  tag.
and do the following:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#distroy").click(function()
      {
       //Your Code Here
      })
    })
    </script>
```